# Why Memory is leaking in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, memory-leaks

I dont know why this is giving memory leak in xcode 4.2. Since I didn't `alloc` `eventArraySave` do I need to release it? I thought this will be added to the `autorelease` pool.

```
//Unarchive in to array
NSMutableArray *eventArraySave = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:savedfilePathName];
```

Do I need to release it or is there anything wrong in the above code. Also want to stress that I haven't `alloc`ed `eventArraySave` or `init`ed `eventArraySave`. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not release `eventArraySave`. It will be returned to you with a net retain count of 0 (after autorelease). If you're seeing leaks from this line, then that suggests that you are over-retaining it somewhere else, or possibly that you are over-retaining some object that is contained within `eventArraySave` (since this is where that object is allocated as well).

The leak tools do not tell you where your mistake is. They tell you where you allocated the memory that was later leaked.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: I haven't tested it recently, but I think `NSKeyedArchiver` should return you the same class (mutable or immutable) that you archived. I believe you're thinking of `NSPropertyListSerialization` and the collection serialization operations (`writeToFile:...`).

Comment: @Rob: I just tested this on a Mac and you are right. Thanks for correcting me, I'll correct my post.

Answer (score 0):

Leaks is simply telling you that memory was created there, but not released later.

Your task now is to figure out what was supposed to release it, but is not.